# Count frequency of words in a file using python

Tags: python, split

I am having a file which has a paragraph. I just want to count frequency of each word. I have tried it in the following way. But I am not getting any output. Can anyone please help me.

```
dic = {}
with open("C:\\Users\\vWX442280\Desktop\\f1.txt" ,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        l1 = line.split(" ")
        for w in l1:
            dic[w] = dic.get(w,0)+1
print ('\n'.join(['%s,%s' % (k, v) for k, v in dic.items()]))
```

I am getting output like this.

```
Python,2
is,3
good,1
helps,1
in,2
machine,2
learning,1
learning,1
goos,1
python,1
famous,1
kill,1
the,1
machine,1
it,1
a,1
good,1
day,1
```

Comment: With your update to the question, what is your problem? It seems like the code works fine.

Comment: "I am not getting any output" ... "I am getting output like this." -- which is it? You are getting output or you are not getting output?

Comment: @chrisz I did some changes, can you please check now.

Comment: @Khelwood Sorry, I did some changes. I forgot to edit this "I am not getting any output" in question.

Comment: @Vivek with your changes, I really don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: This question has a lot of solutions - did any work or help you at all?

Comment: @chrisz , sorry, I am not that good in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure python way without importing any libraries. More code, but I wanted to wtite some bad code today (:

```
file = open('path/to/file.txt', 'r')
content = ' '.join(line for line in file.read().splitlines())
content = content.split(' ')
freqs = {}
for word in content:
    if word not in freqs:
        freqs[word] = 1
    else:
        freqs[word] += 1
file.close()
```

This uses a python dictionary to store the words and the amount of times they appear.
I know it's better to use `with open(blah) as b:` but this is just to get the idea across. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `Counter` object from `collections` module perfectly fits that purpose, and is part of standard library.

Comment: @Guybrush I understand this  but I feel the OP will learn more from seeing raw code instead of letting it be "magic" that they don't understand fully.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I spotted the following issues

- `for s in l`: `l` is a line of text, the for loop will loop through each character, not word
- The `f.split('\n')` expression will generate an error because `f` is a file object, and it does not have the `.split()` method, string does

With that in mind, here is a rewrite of your code to make it works:

```
dic = {}
with open("f1.txt" ,'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        for w in l.split():
            dic[w] = dic.get(w,0)+1
print ('\n'.join(['%s,%s' % (k, v) for k, v in dic.items()]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `count` method

```
mystring = "hello hello hello"
mystring.count("hello")  # 3
```